# How does A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC' simplify to (A + B)C'?

Tags: boolean-algebra

How does A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC' simplify to (A + B)C'?

At least that's what I think the notation commonly used here seems to indicate, but I'll write it out just in case I goofed. I haven't touched Boolean algebra in over ten years and I haven't manually handling algebra in about just as long...

(Not-A and B and Not-C) or (A and Not-B and Not-C) or (A and B and Not-C) simplifies to (A or B) and Not-C

I'm going through, "[The Elements of Computing Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HHORGA)", and where this shows up, they show a truth table that can be simplified down to (A + B)*C' without bothering to explain how or why.

`A|B|C| f(a,b,c)
0|0|0| 0
0|0|1| 0
0|1|0| 1 -> A'BC'
0|1|1| 0
1|0|0| 1 -> AB'C'
1|0|1| 0
1|1|0| 1 -> ABC'
1|1|1| 0`

Pre-simplified: `A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC'`

Simplified: `(A + B)C'`

I completely understand how they got the non-simplified result from the table. The simplification part is what is confusing me. I've looked up some of the laws and theorems, and I'm sure they explain this, but I'm rusty and am having a hard time correlating the steps in-between to these individual laws/theorems.

If someone could break down each step for me with an explanation, I think that would help me a lot. I noticed that Not-C is consistent per part pre-simplified, so isolating that seems to make sense as it's shared across the three, but it's the rest that has me confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to simplify $A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC'$ to $(A+B)C'$ algebraically.

\begin{align}
& \hspace{0.25 in} A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC'
\\
&=(A'B+AB'+AB)C'
\\
&=(A'B+AB'+AB+AB)C'
\\
&=(AB+AB'+AB+A'B)C'
\\
&=(A(B+B')+(A+A')B)C'
\\
&=(A+B)C'
\end{align}

In going from line 2 to 3, we've used the fact that $AB = AB+AB$. In going from line 3 to line 4, we'be just rearranged terms. Let me know if any other steps aren't clear.

Comment: Thanks! That's a big help. I only have one point of confusion left: the very last one, from `(A(B+B')+(A+A')B)C'` to `(A+B)C'` -- I'm not sure how that is being simplified.

Comment: Since $B+B'$ is always true, $A(B+B') = A$. Similarly, since $A+A'$ is always true, $(A+A')B = B$.

Comment: Fantastic! No more gaps ^_^ Thank you, JimmyK4542!

Answer (score 0):

Y=AB'C'+ABC'+ABC+AB'C+A'BC'+A'B'C

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).